# Calculate column in datagriveiw in vb.net

Tags: vb.net-2010

I have the following datagriview

```
ProdId  |    ProdName     |   Qty   |     Price/1 Unit   |    SubTotal

001     |    Coca Cola    |   14    |     5$             |     70$ ?
002     |    Angkor       |   20    |     15$            |     300$ ?
```

1) How to get `SubTotal=70$`
2) `Amount =370$`

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you simply do the calculations when you're loading the data into the grid?

Or just run an event after the user modifies the value of the Qty or Price columns to recalculate the value in the subtotal column?